# Getting the line above a search value in python

Tags: python, regex, sed, multiline

I have a text file that I want to search for a specific ip address, and the way the text file is set up is that the host name is above the ip add. ie

```
real HOSTNAME

address xx.xx.xx.xx
```

What is the best/simplest way to go about getting the hostname when I only got the ip address to search on?  Regular expressions? Is there a sed like utility in python that has a hold space? Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many lines the hostname is before the ip then you could enumerate a list of lines, and subtract the necessary number of lines from the current index:

```
lines = open("someFile", "r").read().splitlines()
IP = "10.10.1.10"
hostname = None
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if IP in line:
        hostname = lines[i - 1]
        break

if hostname:
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

A regex is likely this simplest solution.

```
>>> textdata = '''
someline
another line
real HOSTNAME

address 127.0.0.1
post 1
post 2
'''
>>> re.findall('^(.*)$\n^.*$\naddress 127.0.0.1', textdata, re.MULTILINE)
['real HOSTNAME']
```

You could also use the [linecache module](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html#module-linecache) or simply read all the lines into a list using `f.readlines()`.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe not the best solution, but you can use deque to catch n lines above your target line:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import takewhile

test = """
real others

address xxx.xxx.xxx

real local

address 127.0.0.1

real others

address xxx.xxx.xxx
""".split("\n")

pattern = "address 127.0.0.1"
print deque(takewhile(lambda x:x.strip()!=pattern, test), 2)[0]
```

change the test variable to file("yourfilename") to read lines from your text file.

Comment: Nice use of the *maxlen* argument :-)